# accordion insideYii Clistview - not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, yii

i m using Yii framework component CLISTVIEW on page load with ajax accordion stop working

i have tried follow, but it didn't work

```
$(".items").on('load',function(){
$(this).accordion();
```

});

when i change the event type in **on** form load to ***click*** it starts working. what would be the right event type to call here.

Comment: can you add more code from the rest of the view, so that there is some more context to the question. it'll make it easier to give you suggestions/solutions

Answer (score 0):

Accordion plugin expects this kind of content:

```
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div>
    <p>Content section 1</p>
</div>
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div>
    <p>Content section 2</p>
</div>
```

But if I've understand your situation, you have this kind of code:

```
<body>
    <div class="items">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>Content section 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
            <p>Content section 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

With this script firs I .wrapAll .items elements and then I rewrite elements as accordion plugin want:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.items').wrapAll($('<div>').attr('id','accordion'));
            $.each($('.items'),function(){
                $(this).remove();
                $('#accordion').append($(this).html());
            });
            $('#accordion').accordion();
        });
    </script>
```

HTML will be:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
       <p>Content section 1</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Content section 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And accordion will work fine.